# Create a structure with a cell of variable names and a cell of double arrays

Tags: matlab

[image]

As shown above, I have two cells: one with variable names and another their values.  I need to create a structure in the following form:

```
s = struct;

s.var1.Time = 1st column of 1st val_vars;
s.var1.Data = 2nd column of 1st val_vars;

s.var2.Time = 1st column of 2nd val_vars;
s.var2.Data = 2nd column of 2nd val_vars;

...
```

Comment: Putting indices into variable names or field names like you do with `s.var1` is usually a bad idea, what do you think about using an actual index? `s.var(1)` or `s(1)`. If so the whole could easily be solved with a for loop.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear.  They actually real names.  I need to have structures that have distinct names of their owns and each has the same set of variable names, but different data.  Then, I need to save those structures into one *.mat file.  I don't have control over the two cells as they are products of another script.

Comment: They actually "have" real names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want good speed, try the below vectorized code:

```
%define sample data
name_vars={'var1','var2','var3','var4'};
val_vars={rand(100,2),rand(100,2),rand(100,2),rand(100,2)};

a=arrayfun(@(x) struct('Time',val_vars{x}(:,1),'Data',val_vars{x}(:,2)),1:length(name_vars),'uni',false);
b=cell2struct(a,name_vars,2)
```

Comment: wow...speechless.  Now I can understand it, but it could never come out of my head.  It works like a charm.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution. However, if you are dealing with a large dataset where you have many many `var`s, this approach is [not efficient](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

```
for i = 1:4
  eval(['s.' name_vars{i} '.Time = val_vars{' num2str(i) '}(:,1);']);
  eval(['s.' name_vars{i} '.Data = val_vars{' num2str(i) '}(:,2);']);
end
```

Comment: [**Eval is evil.**](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) And certainly not necessary here.